# GEE problem in classification of China city

Tags: google-earth-engine

When I used random forest to classify Hangzhou (China) in Google Earth Engine, the code editor displays that "Image (Error)Image.select: Pattern 'B1' did not match any bands."And when I delete the "B1", "B2" shows the same error.
I have no idea how to solve the problem.

code below:
//监督分类 (Supervised Classification)

```
/**
unbuilding 0
building 1
*/       
var build_sample = ee.FeatureCollection("users/425490093/Tpoint");
Map.addLayer(build_sample, {}, "build_sample");

function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;

  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));

  // Return the masked image, scaled to reflectance, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B[0-9]*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}


//NDVI
function NDVI(image) {
  return image.addBands(
    image.normalizedDifference(["B5", "B4"])
         .rename("NDVI"));
}

//NDWI
function NDWI(image) {
  return image.addBands(
    image.normalizedDifference(["B3", "B5"])
         .rename("NDWI"));
}
  
//NDBI
function NDBI(image) {
  return image.addBands(
    image.normalizedDifference(["B7", "B5"])
         .rename("NDBI"));
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate('2017-06-15', '2017-06-30')
    // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
    .filterBounds(roi)//
    /**.map(maskL8sr)
    .map(NDVI)
    .map(NDWI)
    .map(NDBI);*/
var bands = [
  "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7","B8","B11",
  "NDBI", "NDWI", "NDVI"];

var l8Image = collection.median()
                   .clip(roi)
                   .select(bands);
                   print(l8Image);

var rgbVisParam = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"]
};
Map.addLayer(l8Image, rgbVisParam, "l8Image");

//切分生成训练数据和验证数据
build_sample = build_sample.randomColumn('random');
var sample_training = build_sample.filter(ee.Filter.lte("random", 0.7)); 
var sample_validate  = build_sample.filter(ee.Filter.gt("random", 0.7));

print("sample_training", sample_training);
print("sample_validate", sample_validate);

//生成监督分类训练使用的样本数据
var training = l8Image.sampleRegions({
  collection: sample_training, 
  properties: ["value"], 
  scale: 30
});
//生成监督分类验证使用的样本数据
var validation = l8Image.sampleRegions({
  collection: sample_validate, 
  properties: ["value"], 
  scale: 30
});

//初始化分类器
var classifier = ee.Classifier.randomForest(5).train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: "value",
  inputProperties: bands
});

//影像数据调用classify利用训练数据训练得到分类结果
var classified = l8Image.select(bands).classify(classifier);
// 对测试数据进行预测
var test = validation.classify(classifier);
// 制作混淆矩阵，并打印出来
var confusionmatrix = test.errorMatrix("value", 'classification');
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
Map.addLayer(roi);
Map.addLayer(classified.clip(roi), {min: 0, max: 2, palette: ['red', 'blue']})
print('confusion Matrix', confusionmatrix);
print('accuracy',confusionmatrix.accuracy());
print('consumersAccuracy',confusionmatrix.consumersAccuracy());
print('producersAccuracy',confusionmatrix.producersAccuracy());
print('kappa',confusionmatrix.kappa());
```

Comment: if it is GEE code provide link to the code

Comment: @ilnaug, kindly translate the language used, it would be easy for others to understand.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2F425490093%2Fbuilding%3ARF_Landsat here is the code